# How to apply pipe to value in RouterLink?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular7-router

I have the following route in Angular 7:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/categories', {{ category.name | slugify }}, category.id]">{{category.name}}</a>
```

The problem is with applying the pipe `slugify` within the `routerlink`.

How can I apply a pipe to a value inside `routerLink`?

Comment: what is the issue, any errors?

Comment: is slugify an angular pipe?

Comment: Yes, slugify is an angular pipe

Comment: could you try with `[routerLink]="['/categories', category.name | slugify, category.id]"`?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo That worked! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the curly brackets like this:

`<a [routerLink]="['/categories', category.name | slugify, category.id]">{{category.name}}</a>`

You don't need them there because you are using property binding which is already evaluating to TypeScript code.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that you can use pipe directly when binding an array

Answer (score 2):

what about this

```
<a [routerLink]="['/categories', slugifyPipe.transform(category.name), category.id]">{{category.name}}</a>
```

and in your constructor,

```
constructor(private slugifyPipe: SlugifyPipe) {
}
```

also you need to provide `SlugifyPipe` in your module providers

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to apply a pipe on a string and a variable you can do the following thing:

```
<button [routerLink]="['/thema' | routeT, category.id, category.catUrlParam | seoFriendlyFormat]">{{category.text}}</button>
```

*routeT* pipe is applied on the '/thema' string, *seoFriendlyFormat* pipe is applied on the 'category.catUrlParam' variable.